# Redux Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'types' before initialization when using store in redux actions

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I want to use redux store values in actions so that additional fetch requests can reduced if the required data is already present in the state. It was working fine as expected but when I closed the server and started working on it next day I am seeing this error on console and not able to see anything on the screen.

Please somebody help what is the issue here :

Error -

```
    movieList.js:34 Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'types' before initialization
        at Module.types (movieList.js:34:1)
        at searchMoviesReducer (searchMovies.js:12:1)
        at redux.js:436:1
        at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
        at assertReducerShape (redux.js:434:1)
        at combineReducers (redux.js:499:1)
        at Module../src/redux/store.js (store.js:7:1)
        at Module.options.factory (react refresh:6:1)
        at __webpack_require__ (bootstrap:24:1)
        at fn (hot module replacement:61:1)
```

action movieList.js -

```
    import axios from "axios";
    import store from "../store";
    
    const types = {
      SET_MOVIES: "SET_MOVIES",
      LOADING_MOVIE: "LOADING_MOVIE",
      ERROR_LOADING_MOVIES: "ERROR_LOADING_MOVIES",
    };
    
    const discoverMovies = (page) => async (dispatch) => {
      const cached = store.getState().movies.pages.find(p => p === page);
      if(cached)
        return dispatch({type: "CACHED"});
      
      dispatch({type: types.LOADING_MOVIE});
      let cancel;
      axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/discover/movie",
        params: {api_key: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY, page},
        cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken((c) => (cancel = c)),
      }).then((res) => {
        dispatch({
          type: types.SET_MOVIES,
          payload: {movies: res.data.results, page},
        });
      }).catch((err) => {
        if(axios.isCancel(err)) return;
        dispatch({type: types.ERROR_LOADING_MOVIES})
      });
      return () => cancel();
    };
    
    export {discoverMovies, types};
```

reducer movieList.js -

```
    import {types} from "../actions/movieList";
    
    const initialState = {
      movies: [],
      loading: false,
      hasMore: false,
      error: false,
      pages: [],
    };
    
    const movieReducer = (state = initialState, {type, payload}) => {
      switch(type){
        case types.SET_MOVIES:
          return {
            ...state,
            movies: [...new Set([...state.movies, ...payload.movies])],
            hasMore: payload.movies.length > 0,
            loading: false,
            error: false,
            pages: [...new Set([...state.pages, payload.page])]
          };
        case types.LOADING_MOVIE:
          return {
            ...state,
            loading: true,
            error: false,
          };
        case types.ERROR_LOADING_MOVIES:
          return {
            ...state,
            error: true,
            loading: false,
          }
        default:
          return state;
      }
    }
    
    export default movieReducer;
```

action searchMovies.js -

```
    import axios from "axios";
    import store from "../store";
    
    const types = {
      SEARCHING_MOVIE: "SEARCHING_MOVIE",
      SET_SEARCH_RESULTS: "SET_SEARCH_RESULTS",
      ERROR_SEARCHING_MOVIES: "ERROR_SEARCHING_MOVIES",
      CLEAR_SEARCH_RESULTS: "CLEAR_SEARCH_RESULTS",
    };
    
    const searchMovies = (query, page) => async (dispatch) => {
      const cached = store.getState().searchMovies.pages.find((p) => p === page);
      if (cached) return dispatch({type: "CACHED"});
    
      dispatch({type: types.SEARCHING_MOVIE});
      let cancel;
      axios({
        method: "GET",
        url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/movie",
        params: {api_key: process.env.REACT_APP_API_KEY, query, page},
        cancelToken: new axios.CancelToken((c) => (cancel = c)),
      })
        .then((res) => {
          dispatch({
            type: types.SET_SEARCH_RESULTS,
            payload: {results: res.data.results, page},
          });
        })
        .catch((err) => {
          if (axios.isCancel(err)) return;
          dispatch({type: types.ERROR_SEARCHING_MOVIES});
        });
      return () => cancel();
    };
    
    const clearSearchResults = () => async (dispatch) =>
      dispatch({
        type: types.CLEAR_SEARCH_RESULTS,
      });
    
    export {searchMovies, clearSearchResults, types};
```

reducer searchMovies.js -

```
    import {types} from "../actions/searchMovies";
    
    const initialState = {
      seaching: false,
      error: false,
      results: [],
      pages: [],
    };
    
    const searchMoviesReducer = (state = initialState, {type, payload}) => {
      switch (type) {
        case types.SEARCHING_MOVIE:
          return {
            ...state,
            searching: true,
          };
        case types.ERROR_SEARCHING_MOVIES:
          return {
            ...state,
            searching: false,
            error: true,
          };
        case types.SET_SEARCH_RESULTS:
          return {
            ...state,
            error: false,
            searching: false,
            results: [...new Set([...state.results, ...payload.results])],
            pages: [...new Set([...state.pages, payload.page])],
          };
        case types.CLEAR_SEARCH_RESULTS:
          return {
            ...state,
            pages: [],
            results: [],
          };
        default:
          return state;
      }
    };
    
    export default searchMoviesReducer;
```

Comment: Have you tried to define `types` outside the movieList action? Somewhere in a file of constants...

Comment: No I have not tried yet but let's also try this.

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito thanks yes it is working now and the error in the console also disappered.